# XPath Specific Question, Selecting a child given value of another child

Tags: xpath

I need to retrieve all of these types of nodes: 
`<parameter value="thisisthename" name="parameters" />`
where 
`type = MyTest`
and one of the child `<parameter value="c:\temp\svn.exe" name="file" />`  equals `c:\temp\svn.exe`

Right now I have

```
ert[type='MyTest']/parameters/parameter[@value='c:\temp\svn.exe']

  <ert agents="0031">
  <type>MyTest</type> 
  <parameters>
  <parameter value="c:\temp\svn.exe" name="file" /> 
  <parameter value="thisisthename" name="parameters" /> 
  <parameter value="200" name="count" /> 
  </parameters>
  </ert>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are almost there. This is the XPath expression you're looking for:

```
/ert[type='MyTest']/parameters/parameter[@value='c:\temp\svn.exe']/../parameter[@value='thisisthename']
```

The idea is that you can move up the xml tree using `/..`.

If you happen to know that `c:\temp\svn.exe` is always somewhere before the `parameter` node you want, you could also use:

```
/ert[type='MyTest']/parameters/parameter[@value='c:\temp\svn.exe']/following-sibling::parameter[@value='thisisthename']
```

This may be a little faster since no backtracking will occur.

Comment: If this is the answer you were looking for, could you mark it as answered?

Answer (score 0):

I go back to this site whenever I have XPath questions...hopefully it helps you.

http://www.w3schools.com/XPath/xpath_syntax.asp

Answer (score 0):

> I need to retrieve all of these types
>   of nodes: `<parameter
>   value="thisisthename"
>   name="parameters" />` where `type =
>   MyTest` and one of the child `<parameter
>   value="c:\temp\svn.exe" name="file" />`
>   equals `c:\temp\svn.exe`

All this **three** conditions, in Xpath:

```
/ert[type='MyTest']
    [parameters/parameter[@value='c:\temp\svn.exe']]
    /parameters/parameter[@value][@name]
```

This means: *from an `ert` root element having a `type` child with "MyTest" string value and a `parameters/parameter` grandchild with `value` attribute equal to "c:\temp\svn.exe", I want all `parameters/parameter` grandchidren having `value` and `name` attributes.*